# Uploadifive total size

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I just bought the Uploadifive and I want to know: how can I limit the total file size? I mean, there is more than one file, how can I limit the total file size?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**onAddQueueItem**](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/onaddqueueitem/) event. It provides the file size in bytes.

Add the sizes of all the files added and you can get total file size.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var bytesLoaded = 0;

$(function () {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'uploadScript': 'upload.php',
    'onAddQueueItem' : function(file) {
                bytesLoaded += file.size;
    },
    'onQueueComplete': function (uploads) {
                alert('Total bytes uploaded: ' + bytesLoaded);
    }
    });
});

</script>
```

If the file size crossed the max allowed size, you can use the [**cancel**](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/cancel-2/) method to remove the file from the queue.

Most probably, you would have solved this issue by now as the question has been posted about 5 months ago. Just sharing my answer for anybody else who happen to reach here.